# ASM x86 is it correct pop immediately after cmp?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

Sometimes I need store values in stack and than compare it. So, I do something like this:

```
Check:
  push eax          ; save
  mov eax, edx      ; calc edx+esi+8
  add eax, esi
  add eax, 8
  cmp eax, [SomeVar]
  jne Code          ; if not goto Code
  pop eax           ; restore stack
  jmp Exit          ; quit

Code:
  pop eax           ; restore stack if no

Exit:
...
```

So, is it correct way to do popping that way (only once):

```
Check:
  push eax          ; save
  mov eax, edx      ; calc edx+esi+8
  add eax, esi
  add eax, 8
  cmp eax, [SomeVar]
  pop eax           ; <-- pop after cmp
  jne Code          ; <-- jump after pop
  jmp Exit          ; quit

Code:
  ; pop eax         ; no pop needs here

Exit:
...
```

Comment: Either way works (since `pop` does not modify flags), but obviously the second way is more compact. I also note that you could reduce `jne Code; jmp Exit` to `je Exit`, but I guess this is just sample code.

Comment: "calc edx+esi+8" you may want to have a look at what `lea`does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Pop does not change the flags, so putting the pop after the comparison before the conditional branch is fine.